# legend tags ignoring mouse events in latest Edge Canary build

Tags: mouseevent, legend, microsoft-edge

HTML
Create a fieldset with a legend and some other tags inside.
CSS
legend:hover { background-color:yellow; }

The legend will not hover nor will any mouse event respond on it.
There is no issue in Chrome or Firefox. This worked fine in a previous build of Canary

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on Edge Canary 87.0.641.0. It works well in Edge Stable 85.0.564.51. I suggest you can wait for the stable release of the version you tried. Besides, you can also provide feedback about this issue using the [Send feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWBKj.png) option in Edge Canary. As Edge Canary is updated daily, you can check often to see if there's any update about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Version 87.0.644.0 !
Thanks Guys

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.